# VB.net WPF :: Touchscreen does not consistently trigger Click() or other Mouse events

Tags: wpf, vb.net, events, touchscreen

I'm looking into an issue where the touchscreen controls behaved oddly on a self-made numberpad. There are two variants of this numberpad, one is a password box, the other is for normal (visible) numeric inputs.

The project itself is quite complex with many different windows being used.

Both the password and numeric windows function perfectly fine when called from the Main window, however when the numberpad (or the password box, I tried both) is called from windows further down the program, things get a little bit *weird*.

The problem occurs on Windows 10 (dev. PC) and Windows 7 (Active PC).

**Description of the problem :**

When attempting to press the buttons, the button click events do not seem to respond. *After tapping them repeatedly*, the buttons will eventually start to function as intended. Once the buttons function, they remain functional until the window is closed. There is no difference due to press-time, movements, ...

*The window works perfectly fine when using the mouse.*

I need the program to be functional by use of a touchpad AND the mouse (though, ofcourse, not at the same time).

**What I've tried :**

- Handling the touchdown event on the window and using the position coordinates to decide which button would have been pressed.

This works, but **only** for the Touchscreen. Buttons still don't actively react, but the code behind the touchdown event functions as intended.

**This, however, breaks the use of the mouse.**

- Handling both the TouchDown and the MouseLeftButtonDown via the position coordinates

Works perfectly for the mouse, works for the touchscreen ... *until the touchscreen starts triggering **twice** on every button that is pressed*. The touchscreen is then both triggering the TouchDown event, as well as MouseLeftButtonDown event. Same applies as previously, as soon as it starts triggering twice, it keeps triggering twice.

- Handling the MouseLeftButtonDown via position coordinates, ignoring the TouchDown

Exact same behaviour as the default Button click events. Touchscreen does not function correctly until it does and once working it keeps working as intended.

- Calling Mouse.Synchronise() on the TouchDown or PreviewTouchDown event handler

Saw this as a solution for a similar (but albeit different issue), did not solve a thing on my end.

- Setting e.Handled = true on the caught Touchdown and MouseLeftButtonDown handlers

Same behaviour as originally is the case.

- IsManipulationEnabled="true" on the involved elements

Changed nothing.

**Code :**

- Designer :

  ```
  <Window x:Class="NumericKeyPad"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:REDACTEDNAME"
      mc:Ignorable="d"
      Title="NumericKeyPad" Height="400" Width="400">
  <DockPanel Name="DockPanel" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="NumericKeyPad_MouseLeftButtonDown">
     <Grid>
      <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <RowDefinition Height="10*"></RowDefinition>
              <RowDefinition Height="10*"></RowDefinition>
              <RowDefinition Height="10*"></RowDefinition>
              <RowDefinition Height="10*"></RowDefinition>
              <RowDefinition Height="10*"></RowDefinition>
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="73*"></ColumnDefinition>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="7*"></ColumnDefinition>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="66*"/>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="73*"></ColumnDefinition>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="73*"></ColumnDefinition>
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <TextBlock Name="Textblock" FontSize="24" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" Margin="10,10,30,0" TextAlignment="Center" Grid.ColumnSpan="5"/>
          <Button Content="1" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"  />
          <Button Content="2" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"  Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
          <Button Content="3" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" />
          <Button Content="4" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" />
          <Button Content="5" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"  Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
          <Button Content="6" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" />
          <Button Content="7" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" />
          <Button Content="8" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1"  Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
          <Button Content="9" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3" />
          <Button Content="0" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0"  Grid.ColumnSpan="3"  />
          <Button Content="," FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="3" />

          <Button Content="Back" FontSize="16" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="4" Grid.RowSpan="2" />
          <Button Content="Enter" FontSize="16" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="4" Grid.RowSpan="2" />
      </Grid>

  </Grid> 
  </DockPanel>
  ```
- Code :

  ```
  Public Class NumericKeyPad
  Public Property NewValue As String

  Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
      Try
          Dim btn As Button = CType(sender, Button)
          NewValue = NewValue + btn.Content.ToString()
          Textblock.Text = NewValue
      Catch ex As Exception
          Worker.WriteLog("NumericKeyPad : Button_Click : " & ex.ToString(), "erro")
      End Try

  End Sub

  Private Sub Window_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
      Try

          Textblock.Text = NewValue
      Catch ex As Exception
          Worker.WriteLog("NumericKeyPad : Window_Loaded : " & ex.ToString(), "erro")
      End Try
  End Sub

  Private Sub ButtonBack_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
      Try
          If (NewValue.Length > 0) Then
              NewValue = NewValue.Substring(0, NewValue.Length - 1)
              Textblock.Text = NewValue
          End If

      Catch ex As Exception
          Worker.WriteLog("NumericKeyPad : ButtonBack_Click : " & ex.ToString(), "erro")
      End Try
  End Sub

  Private Sub ButtonEnter_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
      Try
          Me.Close()
      Catch ex As Exception
          Worker.WriteLog("NumericKeyPad : ButtonEnter_Click : " & ex.ToString(), "erro")
      End Try
  End Sub

  Private Sub Textblock_IsVisibleChanged(sender As Object, e As DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs) Handles Textblock.IsVisibleChanged
      Try
          Textblock.Text = NewValue
      Catch ex As Exception
          Worker.WriteLog("NumericKeyPad : Textblock_IsVisibleChanged : " & ex.ToString(), "erro")
      End Try
  End Sub

  Private Sub NumericKeyPad_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded
      Try
          Me.Focus()
      Catch ex As Exception
          Worker.WriteLog("NumericKeyPad : NumericKeyPad_Loaded : " & ex.ToString(), "erro")
      End Try
  End Sub



  Private Sub NumericKeyPad_TouchDown(sender As Object, e As TouchEventArgs) Handles Me.TouchDown
      Try
          Dim position As Point = e.GetTouchPoint(Me.DockPanel).Position

          HandlePoint(position)

      Catch ex As Exception
          Worker.WriteLog("NumericKeyPad : NumericKeyPad_TouchDown : " & ex.ToString(), "erro")
      End Try

  End Sub

  Private Sub NumericKeyPad_MouseLeftButtonDown(sender As Object, e As MouseButtonEventArgs)
      'Try
      '    Dim position As Point = e.GetPosition(Me.DockPanel)

      '    HandlePoint(position)

      'Catch ex As Exception
      '    Worker.WriteLog("NumericKeyPad : NumericKeyPad_MouseLeftButtonDown : " & ex.ToString(), "erro")
      'End Try
  End Sub

  Private Sub HandlePoint(position As Point)
      Try

          Debug.WriteLine("position : " & position.X & " , " & position.Y)

          'determine where the touch event happened

          Dim place As String = ""

          Dim width As Double = Me.DockPanel.ActualWidth
          Dim height As Double = Me.DockPanel.ActualHeight

          'determine row
          Dim section As Double = height / 5.0
          Dim sectionCol As Double = width / 4.0

          Select Case True
              Case position.Y >= 0 And position.Y <= section 'Row 0
                  place = "textfield"
              Case position.Y > section And position.Y <= section * 2 '1-2-3-BACK
                  Select Case True
                      Case position.X >= 0 And position.X <= sectionCol 'Col 0
                          place = "1"
                      Case position.X > sectionCol And position.X <= sectionCol * 2 'Col 1
                          place = "2"
                      Case position.X > sectionCol * 2 And position.X <= sectionCol * 3 'Col 2
                          place = "3"
                      Case position.X > sectionCol * 3 And position.X <= sectionCol * 4 'Col 3
                          place = "bckspce"
                  End Select

              Case position.Y > section * 2 And position.Y <= section * 3 '4-5-6-BACK
                  Select Case True
                      Case position.X >= 0 And position.X <= sectionCol
                          place = "4"
                      Case position.X > sectionCol And position.X <= sectionCol * 2
                          place = "5"
                      Case position.X > sectionCol * 2 And position.X <= sectionCol * 3
                          place = "6"
                      Case position.X > sectionCol * 3 And position.X <= sectionCol * 4
                          place = "bckspce"
                  End Select

              Case position.Y > section * 3 And position.Y <= section * 4 '7-8-9-Ent
                  Select Case True
                      Case position.X >= 0 And position.X <= sectionCol
                          place = "7"
                      Case position.X > sectionCol And position.X <= sectionCol * 2
                          place = "8"
                      Case position.X > sectionCol * 2 And position.X <= sectionCol * 3
                          place = "9"
                      Case position.X > sectionCol * 3 And position.X <= sectionCol * 4
                          place = "entr"
                  End Select

              Case position.Y > section * 4 And position.Y <= section * 5 'NULL-cma-Ent
                  Select Case True
                      Case position.X >= 0 And position.X <= sectionCol
                          place = "0"
                      Case position.X > sectionCol And position.X <= sectionCol * 2
                          place = "0"
                      Case position.X > sectionCol * 2 And position.X <= sectionCol * 3
                          place = "cmma"
                      Case position.X > sectionCol * 3 And position.X <= sectionCol * 4
                          place = "entr"
                  End Select
          End Select

          Select Case place
              Case "0"
                  NewValue = NewValue + "0"
                  Textblock.Text = NewValue
              Case "1"
                  NewValue = NewValue + "1"
                  Textblock.Text = NewValue
              Case "2"
                  NewValue = NewValue + "2"
                  Textblock.Text = NewValue
              Case "3"
                  NewValue = NewValue + "3"
                  Textblock.Text = NewValue
              Case "4"
                  NewValue = NewValue + "4"
                  Textblock.Text = NewValue
              Case "5"
                  NewValue = NewValue + "5"
                  Textblock.Text = NewValue
              Case "6"
                  NewValue = NewValue + "6"
                  Textblock.Text = NewValue
              Case "7"
                  NewValue = NewValue + "7"
                  Textblock.Text = NewValue
              Case "8"
                  NewValue = NewValue + "8"
                  Textblock.Text = NewValue
              Case "9"
                  NewValue = NewValue + "9"
                  Textblock.Text = NewValue
              Case "entr"
                  Me.Close()
              Case "bckspce"
                  If (NewValue.Length > 0) Then
                      NewValue = NewValue.Substring(0, NewValue.Length - 1)
                      Textblock.Text = NewValue
                  End If
              Case "cmma"
                  NewValue = NewValue + ","
                  Textblock.Text = NewValue
              Case Else
                  'Do nothing
          End Select
      Catch ex As Exception
          Worker.WriteLog("NumericKeyPad : HandlePoint : " & ex.ToString(), "erro")
      End Try
  End Sub
  ```

Does anyone have any clue as to what is causing this, and how to fix it?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: It almost sounds like the initial touch is just getting focus to the window and the next touch is performing the click. Do you have any global handlers that are doing anything that could be messing with focus?

Comment: @KevinCook That was what I was initially thinking, however the behaviour I'm encountering persists even when the window has clear focus. Sometimes while pressing the buttons, the touchdown event fires correctly, but the button does not get actively selected. Then all of a sudden, even after 15+ taps with varying intervals and timings, the buttons will start firing Click events as if it was a mouse-click. With no other inputs active, the entire cycle can break again making the buttons irresponsive once more (though my Touchdown handler is still catching all of them).

Comment: *Part 2   --  To me, it appears as if the event is sometimes upgraded to an actual mouse event, even if the TouchDown event was set as e.handled = true. Reading up on this, I've found a topic regardingTouchscreens and WPF, making it seem that "unhandled" touch events bubble upwards as a mouse-event for backwards compatability (which explains the cases of both the TouchDown and MouseLeftDown being fired nearly simultaneously). The advice there was to enable IsManipulationEnabled to stop the bubbling, which changed nothing in the behaviour I'm experiencing.